# Silent accept .pfx certificates

Tags: c++, wix, certificate

Such a problem: I need to import .pfx certificates in my installation (WiX 3.5). I need to accept importing them without any(!) user interaction, even acception (need to be so for testion on building servers and testing makets)

Tried standard WiX solution, using `WiXIISExtension`, but there is no option for quiet(silent) import.

Tried such solutions on C++ (deferred custom actions from dll in wix):

1. Chain `PfxImportCertStore - CertEnumCertificatesStore - CertAddCertificateContextToStore`:
   Certificate manager asked for acception...
2. `CryptUIWizImport` with flag `CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI`: CryptoAPI tried to access to a private key, and manager asked for acception...

Is there any way of solving this? or I really need to write a custom service for acception?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved my problem. In my case it was just the flag of user protected certificate. Just my dummy. but, in these two days I realised:

- Be carefully with the methods of importing certificate. You should know different situations, when you need to use import from file or from context.
- Pay attention to the flags, you used (the more if you use some examples)
- Be sure your certificate has approvals.

P.S. Comment me if somebody needs good examples of working codes of importing different certificates.

Comment: I have a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13478297/395718). I want to silently import self signed (root CA) certificate (.cer) to current user's root store. Do you have solution for that?

Comment: I don't see your email in your profile as you don't see mine, so one of us would have to reveal his address to the public. I'd rather avoid that. I propose that you just post an answer to my question with the code (as I would do anyway if you post me an answer on email). I could then award points to you.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem when trying to add a self signed certificate in Root trust location. It was prompting me the security warning.

[Security Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERFls.png)

With the following code I am now able to add the self signed certificate silently in the Root trust location.

```
HCERTSTORE hUIRootCertStore = CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, NULL, CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Root");
CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO importSrc;
memset(&importSrc, 0, sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO));
importSrc.dwSize = sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO);
importSrc.dwSubjectChoice = CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SUBJECT_FILE;
importSrc.pwszFileName = L"<certificate file>";
importSrc.pwszPassword = L"<your password>";
importSrc.dwFlags = CRYPT_EXPORTABLE;
bRet = CryptUIWizImport(CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI | CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_TO_LOCALMACHINE, NULL, NULL, &importSrc, hUIRootCertStore);
```

If there is any other method please tell me.