# Silently install root certificate in WiX

Tags: wix

How can I silently install root certificates from WiX? I'm installing some root and intermediate certificates, and for root certificates the system displays confirmation dialog showing basic certificate properties and thumbprint. This is relevant code I have, using `WixIIsExtension` mapped in namespace `iis`:

```
<Binary Id="RootCa" SourceFile="Certificates\RootCa.cer" />

<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Component Id="RootCa" Guid="...">
    <iis:Certificate
      Id="RootCa"
      BinaryKey="RootCa"
      Name="RootCa"
      StoreLocation="currentUser"
      StoreName="root"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<Feature ...>
    <ComponentRef Id="RootCa" />
</Feature>
```

Comment: Found this does it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534671/c-and-wix-silent-accept-pfx-certificates

Comment: I found that also, but didn't understand the answer. If an answer exist there at all...

Comment: Did you comment him for help, or private message the OP

Comment: No. The question now is theoretical. I have a solution for my problem that does not require the answer to the question. If someone provides an answer it would be swell, if not it's also fine.

Comment: Can you post your solution, so that others can have it, I want to know, I'm curious ;)

Comment: I did post it. It's written below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom action that Sunil provided is equivalent to `Certificate` component with attribute `StoreLocation="localMachine"`. In my case installing in machine store makes more sense anyway, so I'll go with that. Original question still remains: how to silently install root certificate in user store. If someone has an answer to that question I'll mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 8):

I am using custom action for same

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallCertificates" Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]Certutil –addstore –f &quot;root&quot; &quot;[INSTALLLOCATION]Certificates\CertificateName.cer&quot;" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" />
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an idea, but I'll still use the standard component.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with me, where did you put the certificate?

Comment: I think you'll also need to pass `Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"` to ensure that the custom action runs with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 3):

I`ve been looking for an answer long time ago. So, thats what I have:

WiX Code:

```
<CustomAction Id="ImportCer.Props" Property="ImportCer" Value="[INSTALLDIR]ca\root.cer" />
<CustomAction Id="ImportCer" Execute="deferred"  FileKey="hsminst.dll" DllEntry="ImportCer" />

<CustomAction Id="ImportPfx.Props" Property="ImportPfx" Value="[INSTALLDIR]ca\super.pfx" />
<CustomAction Id="ImportPfx" Execute="deferred" FileKey="hsminst.dll" DllEntry="ImportPfx" />
```

C++ Code:

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UINT __stdcall ImportCer(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
 {
      char szPath[MAX_PATH];

      GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, szPath, MAX_PATH);

      char certFilePath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
  DWORD certFilePathLen = MAX_PATH;
      MsiGetProperty (
           hInstall, 
           "CustomActionData", 
           certFilePath, 
           &certFilePathLen);

      wchar_t certFilePathW[MAX_PATH];
      MultiByteToWideChar(
           CP_ACP, 
           0, 
           certFilePath, 
           -1, 
           certFilePathW, 
           MAX_PATH);

      PCCERT_CONTEXT pCertCtx = NULL;

      if (CryptQueryObject (
         CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
         certFilePathW,
         CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL,
         CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
         0,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         (const void **)&pCertCtx) != 0)
      {
          HCERTSTORE hCertStore = CertOpenStore (
              CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
              0,
              0,
              CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG |
              CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,
              L"root");
          if (hCertStore != NULL)
          {
               if (!CertAddCertificateContextToStore (
                  hCertStore,
                  pCertCtx,
                  CERT_STORE_ADD_ALWAYS,
                  NULL))
               {
                  return -2;
               }

               if (!CertCloseStore (hCertStore, 0))
               {
                   return -3;
               }
          }
          else
          { 
                return -1; 
          }

          if (pCertCtx)
          {
               CertFreeCertificateContext (pCertCtx);
          }
      }
      return 0;
  }

  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) UINT __stdcall ImportPfx(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
  {
       char certFilePath[MAX_PATH] = {0};
   DWORD certFilePathLen = MAX_PATH;
       MsiGetProperty (
            hInstall, 
            "CustomActionData", 
            certFilePath, 
            &certFilePathLen);

       wchar_t certFilePathW[MAX_PATH];
       MultiByteToWideChar(
            CP_ACP, 
            0, 
            certFilePath, 
            -1, 
            certFilePathW, 
            MAX_PATH);

       CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO importSrc;
       memset(
           &importSrc, 
           0, 
           sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO));

       importSrc.dwSize = sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO);
       importSrc.dwSubjectChoice = CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SUBJECT_FILE;
       importSrc.pwszFileName = certFilePathW;
       importSrc.pwszPassword = L"111111";
       importSrc.dwFlags = CRYPT_EXPORTABLE;

       HCERTSTORE serviceStore = CertOpenStore(
            CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
            0,
            0,
            CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG |
            CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
            L"my");

       if (CryptUIWizImport(
            CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI ,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            &importSrc,
            serviceStore
            ) == 0)
       {
           return -1;
       }
       return 0;
  }
```

Hope will help u

Comment: Thank you for the code. It could be useful. The code however uses `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE` flag so it also imports to local machine, like mine code does with `StoreLocation="localMachine"`.

Comment: In my purposes was many other deferred CA, thats why I managed to solve such problem in c++

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with installing certificates with WiX - two problems I got:

1. If you tell WiX to install in the trusted root certificates on the local machine, it does not work, installs in the Personal Store instead.

2. Permissions for certificates installed by WiX (when they have a private key) do not have the Everyone user set up. [You can change the permissions using MMC->Certificate Manager->Local Machine->(locate certificate with private key) Right Click->All Tasks->Manage Private key, which brings up a file permission dialog].

You can avoid both of these problems by using the microsoft winhttpcertcfg.exe [tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I use it in a batch file (see below), and use a WiX silent custom action to call the batch file.  I let WiX install the tool, the certificates and the batch files before executing the batch.  The batch can be setup to delete the tool and certificates after installation.  It can also be used to start a service that WiX installed that depends on the certificates. The use of the batch greatly reduces the number of custom actions in your WiX file.

The consequence of not installing the certificates correctly was an intermittent error (some machines worked, some not) with a .net client "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" exception when doing an http request.

```
REM Batch file to install certificates using WinHttpCertCfg.exe
"[path to installed]winhttpcertcfg.exe" -i "[path to installed]ca.pfx" -a Everyone -c LOCAL_MACHINE\Root  > c:\temp\installcc.log
"[path to installed]winhttpcertcfg.exe" -i "[path to installed]server.pfx" -a Everyone -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My  >> c:\temp\installcc.log
```

I install the batch install and uninstall file in the product.  Then in WiX - note the deferred and impersonated custom action.

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallCustomAction_Cmd" 
    Property="InstallCustomActionQt" 
    Value="&quot;cmd.exe&quot; /c &quot;[#InstallCustomAction.cmd]&quot;" 
    Execute="immediate" />

<CustomAction Id="InstallCustomActionQt" 
    BinaryKey="WixCA" 
    DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
    Execute="deferred" 
    Return="ignore" 
    Impersonate="yes"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="InstallCustomAction_Cmd" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT REMOVE</Custom>
    <Custom Action="InstallCustomActionQt" After="InstallCustomAction_Cmd" >NOT REMOVE</Custom>
...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
...
<Component Id="InstallCustomAction" Guid="{your-GUID}">
    <File Id="InstallCustomAction.cmd" KeyPath="yes"  
          Source="tools\InstallCloudConnectCustomAction.cmd" />
</Component>
```