# How to install self signed SSL cert into store from Wix Installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, certificate-store

I could not find any documentation on how to do this for the current version of Wix Toolset (3.11.1.2318).

Given I have a `cert.cer` file in my `SourceDir` and `INSTALLDIR` how do I put it in the Windows "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store on install?

EDIT:
So I already read the linked answer, its from 2012! and uses Custom Actions. Is there not a better way? I also read: http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/Blog/2009/02/11/installing-certificates-using-wix-windows-installer-xml-voltive/ which does not use Custom Actions, so am confused is there a better way yet or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silently install root certificate in WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478297/silently-install-root-certificate-in-wix)

Comment: You can also check WiX certificate [element](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/certificate.html)

Comment: Didn't test it, but maybe [try this "sample" from github.com](https://github.com/lukaswinzenried/WixCustBa/blob/8d7f4162761c16d48ad4831ebd45033075c6b302/test/data/Extensions/IISExtension/IISCertificateTests/product.wxs). Here is [a generic, stored search](https://github.com/search?q=%3CCertificate+%3CWix+%3CProduct+%3Ciis%3ACertificate&type=Code) for more samples.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, hopefully helpful to someone in the future:

```
<Binary Id="ClientCertBinary" SourceFile="certificate-client.cer" />

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="MyCompany" Name="My Company">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyApp">
        <Component Id="ClientCertComponent" Guid="YOURGUID-2F37-45A7-88DC-C2A7EAD41F96">
          <CreateFolder />
          <iis:Certificate Id="ClientCert"
                           Name="CertName"
                           StoreName="root"
                           StoreLocation="localMachine"
                           Request="no"
                           Overwrite="yes"
                           BinaryKey="ClientCertBinary" />
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<Feature Id="Complete" Title="MyApp" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="AllPublishFiles" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ClientCertComponent" />
</Feature>
```

Thanks to all those who helped.