# Is it possible to have a designated msi component for secure storage certificate?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Let's say there are a bunch of Products being installed on one system. And they all use the same certificate.
When uninstalling each Product a certificate must not be deleted from the Secure Storage if there are other Products left that may use it.

MSI installer uses reference counting for Componenents, thus solving this problem for such resources as files, folders and registry entries.
But is it possible to use a Component to install a Certificate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57184195/9363996 - solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can implement data-driven custom actions that execute based on the Component state. The WiX Toolset, for example, has many of these.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you, please, elaborate a little for the particular case with certificates? Do I have to create some "dummy" Component for this? If so, what resource should I specify?

Comment: It wouldn't be a "dummy" Component it would be a real Component that you manage the GUID for and treat as important as any of your other Components.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57184195/9363996 like this?